# Call plot() in R without producing a plot

Tags: r

I have written some plot methods that I want to do automated unit tests on in R with `testthat`. Doing so fills my test script folder with plot files, which is a nuisance.

My Q: is there a way to plot to a device that just throws the plot away? Sort of like writing a file to `/dev/null`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `help("pdf")`:

> file: a character string giving the name of the file. If it is of the
>   form "|cmd", the output is piped to the command given by cmd. If it is
>   NULL, then no external file is created (effectively, no drawing
>   occurs), but the device may still be queried (e.g., for size of text).

Thus,

```
pdf(file = NULL)
plot(1)
dev.off()
```

doesn't produce any output.

Comment: Is this true only for pdf? jpeg filename doesn't have an option of NULL.

Comment: @zx8754 It appears that only the pdf device offers this option.